# React Native FlatList display on Scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm making a flatlist in which I display the information on the user scroll.
But I don't know why I got this error:

> ERROR  Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `4`. Keys
> should be unique so that components maintain their identity across
> updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or
> omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future
> version.

I don't really know why I got some " key duplication ". There is my code:

```
 const getProducts = (itemId, check, multiSliderValue, offset) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch(
        authAction.GetAllProducts(
          itemId,
          check,
          brand,
          multiSliderValue,
          offset
        )
      ).then((response) => {
        // faites une copie de la liste de données avant de l'utiliser comme source pour l'opérateur de décomposition
        const updatedList = [...informations];
        let counter = informations.length;
        const newArray = response.array.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          key: counter++, // utilisez un compteur incrémental comme clé unique
        }));
        if (newArray.length > 0) {
          setInformations([...updatedList, ...newArray]);
          setOffset(offset + 5);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
        resolve(newArray);
      });
    });
  };

 const loadMoreData = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return; // empêche les appels multiples à la fonction de chargement de données
    }

    console.log(itemId, check, multiSliderValue, offset + 5);
    setIsLoading(true);
    getProducts(itemId, check, multiSliderValue, offset)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          // mettez à jour votre liste de données avec les nouvelles données
          setInformations([...informations, ...response]);
          // mettez à jour l'offset
          setOffset(offset + 5);
        } else {
          console.log("NO RESPONSE");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

there is my FLatlist :

```
<FlatList
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          onEndReached={loadMoreData}
          ListFooterComponent={isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : null}
          style={{top: "2%"}}
          data={informations}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={styles.Products}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate("descriptionProduct", {
                    data: item,
                  })
                }
              >
                <View style={{width: "40%", height: "60%"}}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.imageProduct}
                    source={{uri: item.image_url}}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.productInfos}>
                  <View style={{width: "60%", height: "30%"}}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 15,
                        bottom: "340%",
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.titre}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      flexDirection: "row",
                      bottom: "1%",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={{color: "grey"}}>à partir de </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.price}>{item.prix} €</Text>
                    <Text style={{left: "50%", color: "grey"}}>
                      {item.boutiqueCpt} offres
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      )}
```

And at the start of the page I'm using this hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return; // empêche les appels multiples à la fonction de chargement de données
    }

    getBrands(itemId);
    getProducts(itemId, check, multiSliderValue, offset);
    setIsLoading(true);
  }, [dispatch]);
```

I'm searching since many hours but I don't found the solution so if someone could explain to me. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: It is just a warning, nothing a big issue, If you want to solve this then share full code of flatlist. renderItem especially.

Comment: Yeah but when I update my page with the scroll I got 1000 warnings ^^. ( and I edited my post and added the entire flatlist )

Comment: in informations you have ids for each items?

Comment: yeah normally .

Comment: It's fine i'm stupid .. I just add a key={item.id} in the first view of my flatlist. Thanks you for your responses and  your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to flatlist:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key} //here key should be in your information which is unique for each data item in the information
```

or

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is complaining due to the fact that the key you're using is sometimes the same. In the code block I don't really see you using a key however. Take note that the key is internally used for some optimisations. See documentation for more details how to add the key. In short add the key extractor method that will return the unique identifier for your items

```
(item: object, index: number) => string;
```

[React native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#keyextractor)

Not sure if this is the entire code but if you have a unique value for the items you're rendering over considering adding it, this should stop the warning from happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this add a toString at the end.

keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}